# About memory and delete object in c++

Tags: c++

I will give some examples and explain. First, I declare some object like

`CString* param = new CString[100]`

And when I declare this one, my memory would increase a little bit because it's some implemented string. Then I store this object in some list of CString just like

```
List<CString> myList = new List<CString>; // new list of CString

myList.add(param);
```

This is my question: I wanna know, when I delete myList, my param isn't deleted, right? And memory in param still exists.

Do I misunderstand?

Comment: You are adding CString object when you say List<CString> myList, I don't think so this is best way. store pointers and you are allocating CString and its you responsibility to release it.

Also I have doubt your code is compiling successfully?

Comment: what kind of list is this? MFC?

Comment: Note that C++ is not Java, especially `new` is used differently in C++.

Comment: Impossible to answer, without seeing the definition of `List`. Apparently it has a constructor that takes a `List*`, and when instantiated on a type, it traffics in pointers to that type. Quite an odd class...

Answer (score 5):

That code won't compile because `myList` holds objects, not pointers, and because `myList` is an object, not a pointer, so `new` is illegal there:

`List<CString> myList;` is an object of type `List<CString>`. `new List<CString>;` returns a `List<CString>*`. `param` is a `CString*`. `myList.add()` expects a `CString`, not a `CString*`.

Bottom line: these are all basic concepts, grab a good book and read it. C++ is a complicated language, you can't just learn it from example snippets or assume the same concepts and syntax are the same as other languages.

Comment: I'm sorry about my code. My intention about that list is some pointer list which add parameter `param` and when I delete this list, memory from `param` is still exist. isn't it?

Comment: @barssala the code doesn't even compile, so it can't even run. You can't talk about runtime behavior when you can't even start the program.

Comment: @barssala but in theory, no, if you allocate with `new[]`, you have to explicitly delete with `delete[]`.

Comment: Ok, if it's not a list. If I use `CString* a = param` and `delete a`. What's about that? I mean `param` still exist? Because I delete only obj. a.

Comment: @barssala a is a pointer, not an object. And `a` and `param` would point to the same location, so both would be invalid after the delete. Take my advice and read a book. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb for c++ : If you type `new` you'll need a `delete`, except if you're using some kind of smart pointer.

Notice in your case you'll need to use

```
delete [] param ;
```

As you are deleting an array.

Comment: There are some one new object in function. And I can't delete that parameters directly.<br/> I will give you some examples. <br/> `void test(){ CString* param("sth"); myString = param;//myString is parameters in header file }` and I wanna know that object param in function will exist forever? and I can't delete param because if I delete param, it will cause myString be NULL as well.

Comment: I don't know what CString is. And how you can compare it's pointer to a non pointer string.

Comment: CString is my implemented string and `myString` is defined in header file like `CString* myString`.

Comment: Still i don't understand how you can compare a pointer type to a non pointer type. If MyString i also a pointer you can delete him instead of param.

Comment: My CString declare in header file such as `CString* myString`. So, `myString` is a pointer.

Comment: So you need to delete myString at the end.

Comment: And what about `param` in function?

Comment: You don't need to delete that. Only one delete per new.